# How can I order by a specific order?

Tags: sql, oracle

It would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ORDER("abc","ghk","pqr"...);
```

In my order clause there might be 1000 records and all are dynamic.

A quick google search gave me below result:

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY case id 
 when "abc" then 1
 when "ghk" then 2
 when "pqr" then 3 end;
```

As I said all my order clause values are dynamic. So is there any suggestion for me?

Comment: Put those values in a table if they aren't already. Join against it and order by it.

Comment: Can you describe the criteria for ordering a little more detailed? What does "my order clause values are dynamic" mean? Sample data and expected result would be nice

Comment: Your example isn't helpful as it's still ordered alphabetically in ascending order, so you wouldn't need to define a `CASE` statement. Is this _dynamic_ order by data stored in column(s) in your query's table? It sounds potentially like you need partitioning and ranking, but until you provide more details, including expected results, we can't help.

Comment: I have a user table and all the users are assigned to a particualr group. Now I want to fetch users on a specific order group. Hope I made it clear.

Comment: I am using Oracle database James

Answer (score 0):

Your example isn't entirely clear, as it appears that a simple `ORDER BY` would suffice to order your id's alphabetically. However, it appears you are trying to create a dynamic ordering scheme that may not be alphabetical. In that case, my recommendation would be to use a lookup table for the values that you will be ordering by. This serves two purposes: first, it allows you to easily reorder the items without altering each entry in the `users` table, and second, it avoids (or at lest reduces) problems with typos and other issues that can occur with "magic strings."

This would look something like:

**Lookup Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE LookupValues (
    Id CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    Order INT
);
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    u.*
FROM
    users u
    INNER JOIN
    LookupTable l
    ON
        u.Id = l.Id
ORDER BY
    l.Order
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Brett. I need a query something like below query:
Select * from users order by user_group(select group from master_group order by 1,2 DESC,3);

Where users table contains user_group field of master_group table.